# Haskell text package selection

Tags: haskell, unicode

Back in the day, everybody used to do text processing with `String`. But then some folks pointed out that this is actually very, very inefficient, and the `ByteString` package was born.

`ByteString` is great for handling binary data. But soon people pointed out that `ByteString.Char8` is actually a massive kludge, and what you really want is *real* Unicode handling for external data. And with that, approximately thirty similar but incompatible Haskell packages for dealing with packed Unicode strings were born. And none of them could really get any traction, because... well, thirty is way too many!

My question: Has this problem been fixed yet? In other words, has the community settled on *one* package for doing this job? And if so, which one is it?

Comment: Doesn't [`text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) do the job?

Comment: @LukeTaylor When last I looked, `text` was only one of about thirty similar packages doing a similar thing, but all incompatible. That was a while ago now...

Comment: Things have changed a lot since then.  `text` is far and away the standard for this sort of thing.

Comment: ...which answers my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that the current gold standard is [Data.Text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-0.11.2.0/docs/Data-Text.html), which you can install with

```
$ cabal install text
```

and which you should import qualified as

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
```

You create `Text` values in your code either by explicitly casting from `String`, as in

```
>> let str = T.pack "Hello, world"
```

or by using the `OverloadedStrings` language extension

```
>> :set -XOverloadedStrings
>> let str = "Hello, world" :: Text
```

Comment: Is this in the Haskell Platform?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Yes, see the "Additional Platform Libraries" section --- http://www.haskell.org/platform/changelog.html

Comment: OK, so it's in the platform and it's the recommended implementation. Sorted.